# wpa_supplicant issues on first boot

Tags: boot

So i've read all the related searched on this and haven't found a relevant answer that works for a headless remote boot, so here goes:
I'm setting up a headless repeatable image for Raspberry pi. I'm using Raspbian buster 64-bit lite image.

I've set a default user with userconf which works fine.
I've set the ssh to be auto enabled which works fine.

What's not working is the wlan0 config through wpa_supplicant.

On first boot, all is well and after login, I get the following error:

Wi-Fi is currently blocked by rfkill.
Use raspi-config to set the country before use.

So my wpa_supplicant looks like this(and includes a country= line):

country=CA
update_config=1
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
scan_ssid=1
ssid="SSID1"
psk=[encryptedPasswd]
}
network={
scan_ssid=1
ssid="SSID2"
psk=[encryptedPasswd]
}

Any thoughts on how to get the wlan0 interface to come up properly without running a command post-boot?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet from the end of `do_wifi_country()` in `raspi-config`, which enables the wifi:<sup>1</sup>

```bash
for filename in /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/*:wlan ; do
  if ! [ -e "$filename" ]; then
    continue
  fi
  echo 0 > "$filename"
done
```

I'd suspect this is where the rfkill settings are.  In case it's not clear, each file ending in `:wlan` there is being overwritten with a `0`. Here's what's in that directory for a Pi 4 I have running bullseye:

```bash
> ls -1 /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/
platform-3f300000.mmcnr:wlan  
platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0:wlan
platform-fe300000.mmcnr:wlan  
platform-soc:bluetooth

> cat /var/lib/systemd/rfkill/*
0
0
0
0
```

And here's what's in it from the current (May 3/23) bulleye 64-bit lite image, never booted:

```bash
> cd /mnt/img/var/lib/systemd/rfkill
> ls -1
platform-3f300000.mmcnr:wlan
platform-fe300000.mmcnr:wlan
> cat *
1
1
```

Very likely if you change those to zero, rfkill will be disabled for wifi.
You may also have to add the third wlan "0" entry from the running Pi example (`platform-fd500000.pcie-pci-0000:01:00.0-usb-0:1.3:1.0:wlan`), but try it
without first.

---

1. I think you've pretty much accomplished the other things there, but you might want to take a look yourself.